# Arithmetic Operations on complex type in C not optimized

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, language-lawyer, complex-numbers

I thought the function f below, when compiled, will be optimized and will be equivalent to the function g below.

```
// 4 multiplications and 2 additions.
// 2 multiplications and 1 addition for imaginary part will be discarded.
float f(float complex x, float complex y) {
    return crealf(x * conjf(y));
}

// 2 multiplications and 1 addition.
float g(float complex x, float complex y) {
    return crealf(x) * crealf(y) + cimagf(x) * cimagf(y);
}
```

But, as for gcc,

- with -O3 option, f still does 4 muls and 2 adds.
- with -Ofast option, f is optimized and does 2 muls and 1 add (equivalent to g).

I know -Ofast will ignore some specifications and execute aggressive optimizations while -O3 does not.
But I don't know what specification is respected here by -O3 option and ignored by -Ofast option.

Could anyone explain what I am missing?

(Or just gcc -O3 misses optimization?)

Comment: You might need `-march=whatever` on x86 and x86-64 to make best use of the processor. Maybe `-ffast-math` too.

Comment: A difference is when there are infinities involved, `x*conjf(y)` is a complex number whose interpretation is different from considering just the real arithmetic in `crealf(x) * crealf(y) + cimagf(x) * cimagf(y)`. Testing with Clang shows that, with `-O3`, `f(INFINITY*I, INFINITY*I)` evaluates to infinity, and with `-Ofast`, it evaluates to NaN. But I have to run and cannot report the details at the moment.

Comment: @Shawn Yeah, `-ffast-math` does the trick: https://godbolt.org/z/6GT78q , but it doesn't take care of the corner cases.

Comment: Consider `f(INFINITY*I, INFINITY*I)`. Then `x*conjf(y)` is a NaN—although, if you calculate its real part alone, you get ∞, the complete result is ∞+NaN•i. So the complex number considered as a whole is a NaN. So `creal(x*conjf(y))` should be a NaN. Oddly, with `-O3`, Apple Clang gets ∞, which is the “wrong” result, while, with `-Ofast`, it gets NaN, which is the “right” result. Looking at the [Godbolt assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/j4qva1), I think GCC may be reversed. In any case, in the assembly code, you can see a `ucomiss` instruction; the compilers are explicitly testing for NaN.

Comment: Missing corner cases is a consequence of using `-ffast-math`, yes.

Answer (score 2):

`-Ofast` enables all optimization options that `-O3` enables but includes for instance also `-ffast-math`.

The `-ffast-math` is most likely the explanation for the difference. It breaks IEEE754 conformance for the sake of speed.

You should note that it is "wrong" to implement complex multiplication using the school type formula `re(A)*re(B) - im(A)*im(B) + i*(...)`. I write "wrong" in quotes because it is optional for the compiler to implement correct behavior (correct in the sense that it behaves in the spirit of IEEE754).

In case you have `Inf` or `NaN` in your source operands A or B the formula gives incorrect results.

Since `-ffast-math` assumes that `Inf` or `NaN` do *not* occur in calculations, the compiler is free to use the school type formula. Otherwise it may emit more complex code that gives correct results for all valid inputs including `Inf` and/or `NaN`.

Comment: What output do you get from GCC for `printf("%g\n", f(INFINITY*I, INFINITY*I));` with `-O3` and `-Ofast`? With Clang, I get “inf” and “nan”, respectively, when I would have expected the reverse.

Comment: Thank you for a good example, Eric.

```
int main(void)
{
    float inf = 1.0f / 0.0f;
    float complex x = inf * I;
    float complex y = inf * I;
    printf("%g, %g\n", f(x, y), g(x, y));
    float s = crealf(x);
    printf("%g\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

I got,
```
$ gcc -O3 test.c && ./a.out 
inf, -nan
-nan

$ gcc -Ofast test.c && ./a.out 
inf, inf
-0
```

Comment: `float complex x = inf * I; float s = crealf(x); printf("%g\n", s);`
Is the output `nan` expected?
Is this IEEE 754 conformant?

Comment: It seems the problem is `float complex x = inf * I;`. Instead, use `__builtin_complex` to construct x, and I got the same output. f(x, x) == g(x, x) == inf.